# JqGrid DateTime format does not save

Tags: jqgrid

I have a datetime time field in a JqGrid table, but when I try to save the record it always sends me the error: Please enter a valid date - d/m/Y H:i:s

Below the field configuration:

```
{align: "right", dateFormat: "d/m/Y", editable: true, editrules: {required: false, date: true}, formatoptions: {srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s"}, formatter: "date", hidden: false, index: "DATA_CHAMADA", name: "DATA_CHAMADA", search: true, sortable: true}

{align: "right", dateFormat: "d/m/Y", editable: true, editrules: {required: false, date: true}, formatoptions: {srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "ShortTime"}, formatter: "date", hidden: false, index: "DATA", name: "DATA", search: false, sortable: true}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: My JqGrid version is 4.5.4

Comment: Hello Toni, I found out that it has a validation of the date type, if I remove this validation I can save the record. Is there any validation for date-time and time fields?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no date-time validation - we have only date and only time validation. You can build your own datetime validation using a custom type validation.

Comment: Hi Toni! Is there a forecast for date-time validation to be implemented in jqGrid?

Comment: For now I disabled the validation and it worked!

Comment: We will add this in our todo list in Guriddo jqGrid, as far as I see you use the very old version 4.5.4

Comment: Yes, I will start a library update process